# Why don't I find any expected results when google-searching with search terms that start with dashes?

Tags: google-search, search

Background: When I try to google search something like "`gcc -Wall`" (for example,) to find [documentation on the `-Wall` flag's meaning for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), it looks like I get the same search results as if I just searched "`gcc`": None of the results seem to include the text "-Wall" in them.

Why doesn't a search query with search terms starting with dashes seem to work as I intend (return results containing matches of the terms that starts with a dash), and how can I properly query for terms that start with a dash?

Note: Related, but not a duplicate (because it is more general, and the answer is binary-different as a result): [How do I escape Google functional characters?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/75121/305006).

Comment: Meta note: It was discussed where and at what level of abstraction away from command-line arguments / compiler flags to ask this question [here on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385332/997587)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcc -Wall` actually tells the Google search engine to include things that match "`gcc`", and *exclude* things that match "`Wall`". This is because the dash/hyphen character, "`-`", is one of several special characters called "search operators" for the Google search engine.

If you go to ["How to search on Google"](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?hl=en&ref_topic=3036132), it links to [a page about search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) that documents the various search operators and how they work. For this particular one, if you start a term with a dash/hyphen, it will tell the Google search engine to exclude that term from the search. Quoting from the current user documentation:

> **Exclude words from your search**
> Put `-` in front of a word you want to leave out. For example, `jaguar speed -car`

To properly search for pages with matches of search terms that start with a dash/hyphen, use the "exact match" operator: enclose/wrap the term that starts with dashes with double quotes (including the dash/hyphen), like "`gcc "-Wall"`".

The "exact match" operator does what its name suggests: It is used to search for exact matches, and can be used to treat the dash/hyphen as part of the search term for which to find an exact match. Quoting from the current user documentation:

> **Search for an exact match**
> Put a word or phrase inside quotes. For example, `"tallest building"`.